# CSS loading issue with Android ICS

Tags: android, mysql, css, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, dolphin-browser

I have an Android ICS 4.0.3 installed in my phone. I have created one Mobile Web Application (test url http://drupal.langoor.mobi), for which I serve the HTML page from the MySQL database in the backend dynamically.

**Problem**:
The html page is not rendered by the default stock browser of Android and Dolphin browser.
This problem does NOT occure in chrome, firefox, safari mobile browsers.

To figure out the problem, I followed *these approaches*:

1. Used Adobe Shadow to do *remote inspect* of the HTML Page, which did NOT help much becuase I was NOT able to see any error in content loading.
2. Assuming Javascript/jQuery conflicts to be a problem, I tried removing all the linked js files which are served dynamically from server (not Static), then the HTML page was rendering but with no style applied.

I tried searching and found this link but it's not helpful:
[Android - html from android_assets in WebView, CSS not loading in ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142997/android-html-from-android-assets-in-webview-css-not-loading-in-ics)

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging more around Problem, I found that main cause for problem was, `content being sent in Uncompressed format from Server` and because of which Android ICS's default and Dolphin Browser are not able to render it properly.

Here is the link where i have mentioned exact cause of problem.
[Enabling data compression for Apache2 + FastCGI setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726774/enabling-data-compression-for-apache2-fastcgi-setup)

Thanks

Comment: it's great that you solved your problem, you can accept this solution, and ask a new question for the new problem you face. stackoverflow doesn't work like forums, so a specific question, should have only relevant answers. when you ask the new question, you can always link to this question, to indicate to users, that there is some relation. asking another question will also get you more views, which means the likelihood of getting an answer will increase.